Blazor ui telerik chart disappears at seemingly random intervals
The chart SVG or canvas suddenly disappears.
Current Behavior
At seemingly random intervals, the chart SVG or canvas disappears. This occurs when performing actions like hiding the chart line or adding values. The issue does not occur consistently or under obvious conditions.
Expected/Desired Behavior
The chart should behave as expected and not disappear unexpectedly.
